# What kind of electronic component is that? A lightbulb?

Tags: identification, passive-components

Found this component in Canon printer power supply [image: part pic]

It follows a protective varistor in series and is followed by a some kind of serivse terminal that had its own hole in the power supply's case, and is connected to nothing. The component is close to to the AC input on the board, and has AR1 printed next to it [image: AR1 for the component and TB1 for the strange teirminal]

It appears to have infinite resistance and no capacity. It has triangle-inside-circle-symbol: [image: triangle-inside-circle-symboll] folloed by 202 followed by T02E printed on it. Google search gave me nothing.

Comment: Ok, its a surge arrester, explains why its 'AR', but what is the unconnected-porbably-for-serivce-terminal at the end?

Comment: Usually these argon-filled spark-gaps lead to an Earth connection.   Perhaps there's a missing ground-wire with a female pin connector, which has fallen off the pcb pin.